# ASP.NET MVC Core (MVC 6) Facebook login and get claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, facebook-login

I am new to ASP.NET MVC Core, I what I want to achieve is to login the user with facebook account, because this is the only way that the user can login in in our application, and get the claims (first and last name, email, etc).
I know how to enable the facebook login.

```
FacebookOptions facebookOptions = new FacebookOptions();
facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
applicationBuilder.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);

applicationBuilder.UseIdentity().UseFacebookAuthentication();
```

I need help how to get claims from it and where to put that code.

Thank you

Comment: And? Did you get it to work, or running into problems anywhere? Let us know, maybe we can help...

Comment: we decided for another work flow
thnx for the aswer

Answer (score 3):

After you have logged in using Facebook you can retrieve the claims associated with that account in the AccountControllers ExternalLoginCallback method.

```
var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
var name = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName) ??
                       info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
var lastName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Surname);
```

Comment: thnx for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using Identity. But your question is about how to get the claims from the facebook account and not how to persist them. So I hope I can help. I have done it with Cookie middleware. I added 'temp' cookie middleware to catch the ClaimsPrincipal from logging in to Facebook and then I sign in to the 'real' Cookie middleware to persist the enriched ClaimsPrincipal. The relevant piece of code in the Configure method of the StartUp class:

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                LoginPath = new PathString(@"/account/login"),
                AccessDeniedPath = new PathString(@"/account/accessdenied")
            });

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "Temp",
                AutomaticAuthenticate = false
            });

        var facebookOptions = new FacebookOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Facebook",
            SignInScheme = "Temp",
            AppId = "yourappidhere",
            AppSecret = "yourappsecrethere"
        };
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

Note how the SignInScheme of the facebookOptions is "Temp" and the options of the 'temp' Cookie middleware has it's AutomaticAuthenticate to false (because you don't want to automatically persist the ClaimsPrinciple in the temp Cookie, but enriched and all in the real one which is called "Cookie" here).

Then the relevant methods in my controller look like:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var externalPrincipal = await HttpContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Temp");

        //TODO Check external principal and retrieve claims from db or whatever needs to be done here.

        var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim("email", externalPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value)
            };
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "password");
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookie", new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Temp");

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> LogInFacebook(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var queryString = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) ? $"?returnUrl={returnUrl}" : string.Empty;
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = $@"Account/Register{queryString}" }; //new PathString(returnUrl)

        return await Task.Run<ChallengeResult>(() => new ChallengeResult("Facebook", props));

    }
```

Note how LoginFacebook is called via a link on your page or something. Remember how Facebook Middleware's SignInScheme is "Temp" at this point. It's redirected to the "Register" action method. There you extract the ClaimsPrinciple from Facebook with the code:

```
var externalPrincipal = await HttpContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Temp");
```

At this point you can do whatever you need to do with the claims. I extract the e-mail claim as you can see. And I sign in with my "Cookie" sign in scheme, to persist the ClaimsPrinciple in a cookie.

Comment: thnx, I give it a try

Comment: How can I target the facebook login from my WebAPI?

Comment: I don't understand the question I guess. You can call LogInFacebook however you want. There is no difference between Web API Controllers and normal controllers in MVC 6...

Comment: HI Danny. I posted a question on this, and I stucked, can u look at it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38041028/asp-net-core-mvc-login-with-facebook-token